# my dark-mode keeps going off after refreshing page

Tags: darkmode

hello I am having trouble by keeping the dark-mode on when I switch pages or I refresh .
I tried to play with java codes with no luck does anyone know what code should I add over my js so the it saves my theme ?? this is my code thanks in advance
https://codepen.io/wissambattlaxe/pen/xxOvbmL

```
let button = document.querySelector('.onoffswitch-checkbox')

        button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
          document.documentElement.classList.toggle('dark-mode')
        })
```

and this is the website : http://zabri.atwebpages.com/index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to persist the chosen theme, you will have to save the user's choice somewhere. Possible options are:

1. Inside the URL
2. In a cookie
3. In `localStorage`

Then, upon every page load, you will have lookup the saved choice and apply it.

To learn more about using `localStorage`, the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) are a great place to start.

Comment: i want to store it in local storage of any user that visit my page but I don't know the right code that's the problem if u can help me will the code I really appreciate it